# Discord.py - Return Statement causing duplicate messages sent

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a simple command that takes every channel in a specific category and sends them in an `embed`. The channels have an emoji tagged at the end of them and I use that to add a reaction to the embed. With this in mind, not every channel in the category has the same channel format the bot would expect, which is why I added an "ignore" list. The problem I am facing is that the `return` statement is causing the embed to duplicate and mess up.

Current Problem: https://gyazo.com/a258c57b7d5c7a1286128e3643a366eb

Channel Format: https://gyazo.com/5c19fcfc7304a1c88c058843ab8584cc

Expected Result: https://gyazo.com/0c1e25018831baf435618ce54f607f8b

```py
reactions = []
    category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, id=788794712474910771)
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Realms channels')
    for channel in category.channels:
      if channel.id in [788803551974785066, 788803379261997116]:
        return
      else:
        channel = channel.name
        channel = channel.split('-')
        if len(channel) == 2: #realm-emoji
          realm, emoji = channel
          reactions.append(emoji)
          embed.add_field(name=realm, value=emoji, inline = False)
        elif len(channel) == 3: #realm-name-emoji
          realm, realm2, emoji = channel
          realmname = realm + "-" + realm2
          reactions.append(emoji)
          embed.add_field(name=realmname, value=emoji, inline = False)
        else: #realm-name-name-emoji
          realm , realm2, realm3, emoji = channel
          reactions.append(emoji)
          realmname = str(realm) + "-" + str(realm2) + "-" + str(realm3)
          embed.add_field(name= realmname, value=emoji, inline = False)
        msg = await ctx.send(embed = embed)
        for emoji in reactions: 
          await msg.add_reaction(emoji)
```

Any suggestions or tips would help greatly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `return` in a loop it will just exit you should use `continue` to skip the unwanted channels. The way you are getting the emoji and name are not general.

- `my_list[-1]` will get the last element in the list which is the emoji.
- `my_list[:-1]` every element except the last.

```py
@bot.command()
async def checkin(ctx):
    reactions = []
    category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, id=788794712474910771)
    embed = discord.Embed(title='Realms channels')
    for channel in category.channels:
        if channel.id in [788803551974785066, 788803379261997116]:
            continue

        channel = channel.name.split('-')
        # last element is the emoji
        emoji = channel[-1]
        reactions.append(emoji)

        embed.add_field(
            name='-'.join(channel[:-1]), value=emoji, inline=False)

    msg = await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    for emoji in reactions:
        await msg.add_reaction(emoji)
```